# How to setup build artifacts in teamcity

Tags: teamcity

I'm trying to setup a build artifact in teamcity but am having issues. Here's the artifact command:

```
 Services\Windows\ApiRequestProcess\ApiRequestLoggerService\bin\Release\* => F:\BuildArtifacts\Services\ApiRequestLogger
```

And here is one of the errors:

```
16:43:33]: [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [Services\Windows\ApiRequestProcess\ApiRequestLoggerService\bin\Release\* => F:\BuildArtifacts\Services\ApiRequestLogger, teamcity-info.xml]
[16:43:33]: [Publishing artifacts] Sending files
[16:43:34]: Failed to upload build artifact due to error: java.io.FileNotFoundException: F:\TeamCity\.BuildServer\system\artifacts\API Request Logger Service\API Request Logger Service Build\536\F:\BuildArtifacts\Services\ApiRequestLogger\ApiRequestCore.dll (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well your issue is TeamCity stores artifacts in its data directory so you cannot specify an absolute location. Do you need the artifacts in that location? If so you will have to run a task to copy them from the artifacts folder (there is a [rest api](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD6/Patterns+For+Accessing+Build+Artifacts) to help you with the downloading of artifacts)

From the [docs](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/Build+Artifact)

> TeamCity stores artifacts on disk in a
>   directory structure that can be
>   accessed directly (for example, by
>   configuring the Operating System to
>   share the directory over the network).
>   The artifacts are stored under
>   /system/artifacts folder.
>   Storage format is described in the
>   TeamCity Data Directory section. Build
>   artifacts are not archived in TeamCity
>   and stay as they are (uncompressed).

Comment: I tried changing it to a relative path and it still didn't work, no errors but didn't copy anything over.

Comment: [Publishing artifacts] Paths to publish: [Services\Windows\ApiRequestProcess\ApiRequestLoggerService\bin\Release\* => ..\..\..\..\..\..\..\BuildArtifacts\Services\ApiRequestLogger, teamcity-info.xml]
[09:21:22]: [Publishing artifacts] Sending files

Comment: @Justin - you cannot do this - it has to be relative (down) to the root of the build folder inside the teamcity data dictionary.

Comment: @redsquare The pita is that you could do this in TeamCity 6... build/**/*=>C:\Cowantr\trunk\assemblies\ ... but in TeamCity 9 it doesn't throw an error but it doesn't work. :S

Answer (score 2):

@redsquare is correct. TeamCity is archiving artifacts relative to your build. Previous to TeamCity I did it the way you describe too ;)

The real question is why do you want to do that (as your build are already archived)? I'll hazard a guess...

If you are doing it to be accessible for deployment or by another build there is an alternative... In TeamCity speak: Dependencies / Artifact Dependency. You can consume the output of your CI build in another CI build... or in a deploy build in a straight forward manner.

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2161208/how-can-i-have-teamcity-run-a-bat-file-on-each-successful-build/8649550#8649550) for more detail.